# Tableau connection to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I need help connecting tableau to snowflake using single sign on. I don't have a personal account, I'm only open to using a single sign on. Can I get help achieving this? Do I have to be on the same database?

Comment: are you using the ODBC driver of Snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tableau to Snowflake connection is achieved using the Snowflake OAuth mechanism. This involves setting up the OAuth security object on SF as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-partner.html#examples

Once this is done, you can then use OAuth + SAML SSO to authenticate user logging in from Tableau to SF as detailed here: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/snowflake_oauth.htm